# Questions about how does the native VLAN work

Tags: vlan, switching

I am studying about VLANs at the moment and I have a few questions regarding native VLANs and their purpose.

I've read that they are used to carry untagged traffic, and that the native VLAN is configured on trunk interfaces so I must ask.

1. What kind of traffic is sent without the VLAN tag?
2. I've read that the native VLAN should be a different VLAN than the default VLAN 1, for security purposes. What kind of security risks are we exposed to, if we use the default native VLAN of 1?
3. Why should we not assign endhosts to the native VLAN?

Comment: There are many questions about this with answers here, such as the one in the box above. Also, you should only ask one question per post, else your question may be closed as needing more focus.

Comment: VLANs serve many purposes and an untagged or *native* VLAN is just a way to connect a VLAN across (switch) ports.